# Is it possible to specify the theme a Windows Phone 8 app should always use?

Tags: windows-phone-8, themes

My client wants the app to always use a white theme. I'm new to Windows Phone development but from what I see, the theme of the app is based on a setting in the operating system. Can this be overridden so that it always uses white? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jeff Wilcox's 'Windows Phone Theme Manager' nuget package.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager/

Just add a function call to the App constructor:

```
ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();
```